# Interpolate line data to grid matlab

Tags: matlab, line, interpolation

i have a matrix consist of 5 columns the first and second columns are for x_start & y_start of the line, the third and fourth are for x_end & y_end the fifth is -concentration of contaminant in this line- 

for example:

```
%  x_start  y_start  x_end   y_end concentration
frac= [0         0      1       1     0.3
       1         1      3       3     0.6
       3         3      10      2     1.2
       3         3      10      8     0.5];
```

if i assume that i have a domain of interest 10mx10m and this domain is divided by finite difference cell size 1mx1m (i.e domain is 10 cells by 10 cells)

and i want to interpolate the above mentioned line values so that each cell intersects with a certain line can take line's concentration value

Here's an example:
[image: a link]
<sub>(source: [0zz0.com](http://www14.0zz0.com/2015/09/01/21/201797784.jpg))</sub>

for schematic preview of the discretized domain

 the line has a concentration value and the intersecting cells should take same value

i knew about such functions in matlab can do this but unfortunately for scattered points such as

```
   interp2 & griddata
```

i tried a small code for this problem but it still gives error and the `interp2` function is designed for scatter interpolation (points not lines)

```
   [X,Y] = meshgrid(0:10);
   conc=interp2(frac(:,1),frac(:,2),frac(:,5),X,Y);
```

Comment: Try the functions and come back with a piece of code so you can show us what you have tried and why that is not working. This is called a [mcve] and is standard to SO posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show an example with a smaller domain to start with. This will allow showing the intermediate matrices, useful to understand what the code is doing. However, the code is completely scalable to bigger domains and even to curves instead of lines if necessary.

First I need to define the domain limits Then I create a grid.

```
%% // Domain Parameters
domainProps.Xlim = [0 5] ; 
domainProps.Ylim = [0 5] ;
domainProps.nCellX = 5 ;       %// number of cells into the domain (X axis)
domainProps.nCellY = 5 ;       %// number of cells nito the domain (Y axis)

xd = linspace( domainProps.Xlim(1) , domainProps.Xlim(2) , domainProps.nCellX+1 ) ;
yd = linspace( domainProps.Ylim(1) , domainProps.Ylim(2) , domainProps.nCellY+1 ) ;
[Xq,Yq,Zq] = meshgrid( xd, yd, 0 ) ;
```

Nothing too exotic so far. Then I'll define an arbitrary line (*you will have to take the line coordinates from your* `frac` *table*).

I then use `interp1` to re-interpolate the `Y` values of the line on the `X` grid to have the points intersecting the `Y` grid lines.

```
%% // example for first line
xl1 = [0 5] ;      %// X for line 1 - take these data from your table "frac"
yl1 = [1 3.8] ;    %// Y for line 1 - take these data from your table "frac"

%// reinterp the Y values over the X-Grid defining the domain
yi1 = interp1( xl1 , yl1 , xd ) ;
```

So so far we have:

```
%% // display what we've got so far
figure ; grid on ; hold on
hp = plot(xl1,yl1) ;
hpi = plot(xd , yi1,'or')
set(gca,'Xlim',domainProps.Xlim,'YLim',domainProps.Ylim,'XTick',xd,'YTick',yd)
```

[image: linegrid1]

Now comes the fun part. You'll notice that for each point highlighted by a red circle, I should illuminate the grid block on the right *and* the grid block on the left (except on the domain border of course). So all I have to do is to locate which grid line *segments* of the domain are intersected by your line. This can be easily done by comparing the Y coordinates of the grid points (we have that in the matrix `Yq` defined above) with the `Y` coordinates of the line intersecting them (this is `yi1`). So on we go:

```
%// find the elements of the grid lower or equal to the corresponding value of yi
Z = bsxfun(@le,Yq,yi1) ;
%// keep only the "boundary" values (between "0" and "1" domains)
Z(1:end-1,:) = xor( Z(1:end-1,:) , Z(2:end,:) ) ;
%// now replicate the pattern to the left (because each point at
%// intersection must illuminate both block on the left and on the right
Z(:,1:end-1) = Z(:,1:end-1) | Z(:,2:end) ;
```

*details of what is happening here will be given at the end of the answer.

Now you have a logical matrix `Z`, the size of your domain, which contains `1` (`true`) for every block traversed by the line, and `0` (`false`) everywhere else.
So to assign your concentration is now easy, simply multiply `Z` by the desired concentration value and you are done:

```
%% // Assign value to block traversed by the line
conc = Z .* 0.8 ;           %// use the concentration value from your table
figure
hpc = pcolor(Xq,Yq,conc) ;  %// plot the domain with the illuminated blocks

%% // cosmetic changes
set(hpc,'EdgeColor',[0.5 0.5 0.5] )
caxis([0 1])
colorbar
hold on
hpp = plot(xl1,yl1,':k','LineWidth',2) ;
hpi = plot(xd , yi1,'or')
```

et voila:

[image: linegrid2]

---

As I said earlier, this is completely scalable. It will work for larger domain size ... as for not so straight lines:
[image: examples]

---

### Explanations:

*(with a domain size of 5 blocks)*

```
>> Z = bsxfun(@le,Yq,yi1)
Z =
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

But matlab coordinate system is down to top, while the matrix indexing is top to bottom, so to represent the matrix values as you would see the picture, I flip the matrix vertically (just for display though, do not do that in the real calculations).
So:

```
>> flipud( Z )
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

All these `ones` represent the blocks of the domain which are below or traversed by the line. Unfortunately, I only want the "traversed" one, not the one below, so I have to keep only the interface between the `1`s and the `0`s. This is done by shifting the matrix by one row and apply a `xor` filter (again, do not actually use the `flipud`):

```
>> Z(1:end-1,:) = xor( Z(1:end-1,:) , Z(2:end,:) ) ;
>> flipud(Z)
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     1     1     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

And since we said above that both left **and** right blocks of each intersection have to be highlighted, we also replicate the pattern one column to the left:

```
>> Z(:,1:end-1) = Z(:,1:end-1) | Z(:,2:end) ;
>> flipud(Z)
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

we're done :-). Multiply that by the value you want, only the highlighted cells will have a value, the rest will stay at 0.

---

### Important note:

So far I only use the `Y` intersections. It worked very well because the `Y` gradient is smooth (the line having an angle < 45 degrees, it always crosses more `X` blocks than `Y` blocks.
If your line slopes are > 45 degrees, it will be better to use the very same method but invert the axis (reinterpolate your line such as you obtain the `X` values (`xi1`) at the `Y` grid intersections, and do the comparison with `Xq` instead of `Yq`.
If you have a curve which have both vertical **and** horizontal gradients (like my sine wave above if I amplify the magnitude for example), then you will have to use **both** methods (over `X` and over`Y`), then combine the resulting `Z` into one (something like `Z= Zx | Zy`).

Comment: thanks again for your work
but if the x final of the line is less than the domain limit i.e(xf=4) then the code still mark the last cell (5,4) as an active cell (z=1) and this is not the case

Comment: @MohamedIsmaiel. Yes, because as I explained, there is a point **on** the intersection of grid `4` and grid `5`. The point is overlapping both grids so both sides of the intersection will be highlighted. If you change your last `x` value to `xf=4-2*eps` then you'll be all right.