# matlab - find closest points to my line and create an new line with them

Tags: matlab, image-processing, point, closest

I have the image shown below (image 1), and I want to find the closest pixels near my line. 
In image 2 as you can see, the red crosses are the white pixels in my image,and the green are points in my line. The line is displayed with the blue color.
So I want to find which red pixel is closer to green pixel. 
And after that I want to create a new line which passes through the closest points.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

So I have an array with the coordinates of my line points, and another array with the coordinates of all white pixels (red crosses) of my image

I wrote the code below but it finds 100 random points across my line (the one with the cyan circles), which they are not the closest,for example in A2 poisition.

The lineCoord is an cell with arrays lets say 100x2 each: 
(x1,y1) is the starting points of my line, (x2,y2) is the ending points

[image: image3]

```
x1 = lineCoord{1}(1,1);
x2 = lineCoord{1}(end,1);

y1 = lineCoord{1}(1,2);
y2 = lineCoord{1}(end,2);

n = 100;

x0 = linspace(x1,x2,n);
x0 = round(x0);     

y0 = linspace(y1,y2,n);         
y0 = round(y0);

for i=1:length(x0)
plot(x0(i),y0(i),'o','LineWidth',1.5,'Color','c');
end
```

Comment: It's not for your exact problem, but may be you can find some inspiration in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32359970/3460361).

Comment: I’m not really sure what you need. Is it to find a continuous discrete line? Is it to find the 100 nearest pixels? Is it something else? I ask because your description states you want to find the closest points, but you implemented something that is unrelated to the red pixels. I would assume, from your description, that you want to collect all red pixels, find their distance to the line, and then pick the 100 nearest ones. But that does not necessarily lead to a continuous discrete line.

Comment: 1/2    @CrisLuengo You are right i messed up a little bit. 

The hole perpuse is to create a new line above my original line ( blue line). 
This new line must pass through the points in the image (red dots) which they have the smallest distance from my original line . Is it clear now?

Comment: 2/2 So i thought that first i should find the closest points to my line and then create a new line through them

Comment: but then your resulting line isn't going to be a _straight_ line if it has to pass through all these points. Is this really what you want ?

Comment: Hi i found a solution, for my previous problem.
But i have a new problem now:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/462877-group-every-ten-cell-array

Can you help me?